# OpenCL: cannot pass a integer to constant memory

Tags: opencl

I wrote a kernel like this

```
kernel void computeLayerOutput_Rolled(global Layer* restrict layers, constant int* restrict netSpec, __constant const int layer1)
```

But an `cl::Error` occurred when creating the kernel, and the error information is

```
:29:123: error: invalid address space for argument to __kernel function
kernel void computeLayerOutput_Rolled(global Layer* restrict layers, constant int* restrict netSpec, __constant const int layer1)
                                                                                                                          ^
:29:123: error: parameter may not be qualified with an address space

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clCreateKernel
```

when I remove the `__constant` qualifier of `layer1`, everything is OK, but I don't want to put it into the private memory since it might occupy a register in every work item. Passing an array with only one element seems not a very elegant solution either.

I just wondering that is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same 'problem' a while ago. I was used to the way CUDA C/C++ handles constant memory and tried to find a solution to get the same convenience in OpenCL. Long story short, I didn't found one. If you want constant memory you can do two things:

1. pass in a pointer to the constant address space as you suggested, or
2. use #defines and recompile

non of the solutions is very pretty but they do what the are supposed to.

However, if the only problem with passing an integer is the fear of higher register usage than you can go forward and just provide the integer per value. The single integer value will occupy as much registers as a pointer to constant memory if the size of the pointer is 32 bit.

Comment: Do you mean that the address of constant memory values also costs extra register? I have never thought about that... Thanks a lot, Michael

Answer (score 3):

The spec says (labels mine):

> (1) The generic address space name for arguments to a function in a
>   program, or local variables of a function is `__private`. All arguments
>   to a `__kernel` function shall be in the `__private` address space.
>
> (2) `__kernel` function arguments declared to be a pointer of a type can point to one of the following address spaces only: `__global`, `__local`
>   or `__constant`.

In other words, only pointers can be qualified as `__constant` in kernel arguments. `layer1` is not a pointer, so it can't be `__constant`.

> I don't want to put it into the private memory since it might occupy a register in every work item.

`layer1` may *already* be using a register, because it is *already* in private memory: as quote (1) indicates, all arguments to a kernel function are in the `__private` address space, which may map to registers.

To clarify, when writing `constant int* restrict netSpec`, do not confuse:

- Address space *of the pointer* (the argument `netSpec` is in `__private` address space)
- Address space *of the pointee* (what `netSpec` points to is in `__constant` address space)

Comment: In practice arguments may not occupy registers. Whether that "private" data maps to registers or not is really a compiler problem and implementation defined. Some implementations may map kernel arguments into constant memory. Given that they are uniform there would be no way to tell the difference until they are written to, at which point they are promoted to registers. If the argument is a const then it will not be written to anyway.

Comment: @Lee -- I think the compilers _might_ do that, but not _must_ do that. Since I have not add any optimizing flag, I have no idea about that.

Comment: @Young-Bae -- Maybe I am not so familiar with the organization of constant memory. I thought it is like a very big register file and do not need pointers before... Seems like I am wrong

Comment: @ch94 -- True in theory. In practice they will probably either do it that way or they won't. If the implementation is designed such that kernel arguments go into a constant buffer then the runtime will put them there and the compiler will assume that is where they are. The implementation of constant memory varies a lot from implementation to implementation. As you can use __constant pointers in code though it would be hard to do it purely as a register file as it would need some form of computed indexing.